# Computation of the matrix inverse using the Eigen C++ library introduces noise

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I have a publish-subscribe type of a node that receives pose information (position and orientation) from the subscribed data stream and it should compute the inverse and publish out.

In order to do so I'm creating a 4-by-4 homogeneous transformation matrix from the original pose data.

Inverse it using the Eigen C++ template library, convert the transformation matrix back to position and orientation form and publish it.

When I plotted the published data stream I noticed some noise so I ended up publishing the original data too for comparison, here is what I did:

1. convert `original_pose` to TF matrix, named as `original_TF`
2. convert `original_TF` back to pose, named as `original_pose_`
3. publish `original_pose_`
4. inverse original_TF assign to `inverted_TF`
5. convert `inverted_TF` to pose, named as `inverted_pose_`
6. publish `inverted_pose_`

When I plot the X, Y, Z position fields, I'm seeing a significant amount of noise (spikes and notches in the visual below) in the inverted pose data. Since I'm using the same functions to convert the original pose to TF and back, I know that those equations aren't the source of the noise.

[image]

Blue is the original, whereas red is the inverted.

Here is the code. Really nothing extraordinary.

```
bool inverse_matrix(std::vector<std::vector<double> > & input, std::vector<std::vector<double> > & output)
{
    // TODO: Currently only supports 4-by-4 matrices, I can make this configurable.
    // see https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html

    Eigen::Matrix4d input_matrix;
    Eigen::Matrix4d output_matrix;
    Eigen::VectorXcd input_eivals;
    Eigen::VectorXcd output_eivals;

    input_matrix << input[0][0], input[0][1], input[0][2], input[0][3], 
                    input[1][0], input[1][1], input[1][2], input[1][3],
                    input[2][0], input[2][1], input[2][2], input[2][3],
                    input[3][0], input[3][1], input[3][2], input[3][3];
    cout << "Here is the matrix input:\n" << input_matrix << endl;

    input_eivals = input_matrix.eigenvalues();
    cout << "The eigenvalues of the input_eivals are:" << endl << input_eivals << endl;

    if(input_matrix.determinant() == 0) { return false; }
    output_matrix = input_matrix.inverse();
    cout << "Here is the matrix output:\n" << output_matrix << endl;

    output_eivals = output_matrix.eigenvalues();
    cout << "The eigenvalues of the output_eivals are:" << endl << output_eivals << endl;

    // Copy output_matrix to output
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        int in = i/4;
        int im = i%4;
        output[in][im] = output_matrix(in, im);
    }
    return true;
}
```

-- Edit 1 --

I printed out the eigenvalues of the input and output matrices of the inverse_matrix function.

```
Here is the matrix input:
    0.99916 -0.00155684  -0.0409514    0.505506
 0.00342358   -0.992614    0.121267     0.19625
 -0.0408377   -0.121305   -0.991775     1.64257
          0           0           0           1
The eigenvalues of the input_eivals are:
                (1,0)
 (-0.992614,0.121312)
(-0.992614,-0.121312)
                (1,0)
Here is the matrix output:
    0.99916  0.00342358  -0.0408377   -0.438674
-0.00155684   -0.992614   -0.121305     0.39484
 -0.0409514    0.121267   -0.991775     1.62597
         -0          -0           0           1
The eigenvalues of the output_eivals are:
                (1,0)
 (-0.992614,0.121312)
(-0.992614,-0.121312)
                (1,0)
```

-- Edit 2 --

> I don't quite understand what you are plotting. Is it original_pose.{X,Y,Z} and inverted_pose.{X,Y,Z}? Then the "spikes" will really depend on the orientation-part of the matrix.

I am plotting `original_pose_{position.x, position.y, position.z}` and `inverted_pose_{position.x, position.y, position.z}` where the complete data that's published is `<variable_name>{position.x, position.y, position.z, orientation.w, orientation.x, orientation.y, orientation.z}`.

Can you elaborate on "the "spikes" will really depend on the orientation-part of the matrix."?

> Also, how is your description related to the code-snippet? (I don't see any matching variable names).

I've identified that the source of the noise is the inversion, which is the item number 4 in my description: *inverse `original_TF` assign to `inverted_TF`.* To relate one another, I'm calling the function as follows:

```
isSuccess = inverse_matrix(original_TF, inverted_TF);
```

> How do you store "poses" (is that the vector<vector> in your snippet)?

Yes, I'm storing them in 2-dimensional vectors of type double.

> At any point, do you use Eigen::Transform to store transformations, or just plain Eigen::Matrix4d?

No, I'm only using `Eigen::Matrix4d` locally in the inverse_matrix function to be able to make use of the Eigen library for computation.

Comment: Floating-point math is not exact.  If you're unlucky and your characteristics are not similar in magnitude, then rounding error in one may swamp the signal in another.  Can you print out the eigenvalues of your matrix?

Comment: Also note that computing an inverse matrix is not as numerically stable as doing a decomposition (resulting in block-triangular factors) and using this form to untransform your data.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Applications

Comment: @BenVoigt Hi thanks for the information. I added a snapshot of eigenvalues of the matrices not at the very beginning but towards the last portion of the experiment where the noise is severe.

Comment: @BenVoigt should I calculate the LU Decomposition instead of the inverse? Is that the suggested fix?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are plotting. Is it `original_pose.{X,Y,Z}` and `inverted_pose.{X,Y,Z}`? Then the "spikes" will really depend on the orientation-part of the matrix. Also, how is your description related to the code-snippet? (I don't see any matching variable names). How do you store "poses" (is that the `vector<vector<double>>` in your snippet)? At any point, do you use `Eigen::Transform` to store transformations, or just plain `Eigen::Matrix4d`?

Comment: @chtz Hi, thanks. I answered your questions above. Please see Edit 2.

Comment: Regarding the spikes I meant to say, you can't expect the position part of the inverse to depend only on the position of the original transformation. If the orientation of the transformation changes non-continuously, this will generally lead to non-continuous changes in the position of the inverse.